# Query sql slow with order by and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

I'm doing a database query but it's taking a while, I believe it's for the group by and the order by, but I couldn't get better.

```
SET @CODIGO_EMPRESA = 1;
SET @CODIGO_FILIAL = 2;
SET @DATA_INICIAL = '2021-06-16 21:59:17';
SET @DATA_FINAL = '2021-09-20 21:59:16';
SET @SITUACAO_SUP_SANG = 0;

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CODIGO_BOMBA, CODIGO_BICO, ENCERRANTE_FINAL
FROM
    MOVIMENTO_COMB_ABASTECIDAS 
WHERE
    CODIGO_EMPRESA = @CODIGO_EMPRESA
        AND CODIGO_FILIAL = @CODIGO_FILIAL
        AND DATAHORA < @DATA_INICIAL
ORDER BY DATAHORA DESC , ENCERRANTE_INICIAL DESC
) A  GROUP BY CODIGO_BOMBA, CODIGO_BICO
```

Comment: There is no reason to be using a subquery. Stick your group by and order by in the same SELECT statement. It also doesn't make any sense to order your results before grouping them. I would hope Mysql's built-in optimization would figure out what you meant by this statement, so it's unlikely to change the speed at which the query runs. You'll need to supply an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) plan for us to deduce why the query is running is slow.

Comment: I need to use subquery because of order by desc

Comment: @RenathuCazari I recommend you to edit your question and describe better your need.

Comment: I deleted my last comment. Now that I look at your query, I can't even figure out what you are doing. Supplying a GROUP BY here without aggregating any other columns doesn't make sense. I think you are only getting the results you want by luck coupled with the fact that MySQL would even allow such a query where every other RDBMS would just give you an error. Can you share sample data and desired results?

Comment: I need the largest ENCERRANTE_FINAL(decimal) by CODIGO_BOMBA(Int) and CODIGO_BICO(Int) where the DATAHORA(DateTime) is <  that @DATE_INICIAL(DateTime) and DATAHORA(DateTime) is the largest below @DATE_INICIAL(DateTime)

Comment: Get rid of the `ORDER BY`; it is ignored in 'derived' tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [multicolumn index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) to help this query run fast. It should contain the two columns you mention in `WHERE ... = ...` and then the column you mention in `WHERE ... < ...`.

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX MCA_CE_CF_D 
          ON MOVIMENTO_COMB_ABASTECIDAS
             (CODIGO_EMPRESA, CODIGO_FILIAL, DATAHORA);
```

You didn't ask about this, but your query has some other problems. You're misusing [MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). So its SELECT clause is interpreted as if [ANY_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) appeared on the third column.

```
SELECT CODIGO_BOMBA, CODIGO_BICO, ANY_VALUE(ENCERRANTE_FINAL)
```

And, because SQL is a set-processing language, it is free to ignore ORDER BY clauses in subqueries unless they're accompanied by LIMIT clauses. If it somehow is not ignoring your ORDER BY clause, that is nothing but luck.